# Problema com posicionamento de div

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

Boa Tarde galera,

estou fazendo um menu DropDown em um site, eu estou com a seguinte dificuldade,
quando passo o mouse sobre o item, os subitens ficam abaixo de um plugin que uso de banner.

Ex: Se coloco para esconder a div dos banner (display:none), o SubItem aparece e fica por cima do texto de maneira correta, mas se volto a Div do Banner, o subItem fica em baixo da imagem do benner.

Nos subitens estou usando position absolute, nos banner rotatórios existem várias imagens com position absolute também.

Existe como definir quem deve ficar na frente?

Comment: Na `div` do seu dropdown coloca em seu css `z-index:9999;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei seu código. Eu faria o seguinte, por exemplo:

```
.divMae{position:relative; width:500px}
.divFilha{position:absolute;z-index:2; left:50%; margin-left:-250px}
```

Com isso, a divFilha vai aparecer centralizada abaixo da divMae. Se não aparecer, pode ser o seu z-index, só aumentar aí.

Answer (score 0):

Então, fica um pouco dificil sem ver seu código, mas repondendo a questão do posicionamento de qual div fica na frente, utilize o "z-index: 10" no css, o 10 é só para exemplificar, você pode ordenar de acordo com qual vc quer q fique na frente. Quando maior o valor mais na frente ficará a div.

Caso vc possa disponibilizar sua ideia, utilize este site http://jsfiddle.net/, para colocar parte do seu código html, css e javascript, lá fica salvo seu protótipo e vc disponibiliza para nós o link e fica mais fácil para todos interagirem.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Felipe Stoker,

com o z-Index resolveu mesmo, tive que aplicar em cima da div filha igual vc mostrou.

Comment: Só perceba, que a `divFilha` tem a margem negativa que é referente a metade (-) da width da `divMae`, isso é feito para centralizar a div.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, usando  z-index você consegue definir como as camadas (elementos) são renderizadas pelo ser navegador.

Leia [este artigo](http://pt-br.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php), vai te ajudar.